# Swiping ionic cards

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a simple way to make ion-cards swipe rather than stack vertically one above the other?

I currently have the cards stacking vertically using this code:

```html
<ion-content class="outer-content speaker-list">
  <ion-card *ngFor="#speaker of speakers" class="speaker">

    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img [src]="speaker.profilePic">
        </ion-avatar>
        {{speaker.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content class="outer-content">
      <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="#session of speaker.sessions" (click)="goToSessionDetail(session)">
          <h3>{{session.name}}</h3>
        </button>
        <button ion-item (click)="goToSpeakerDetail(speaker)">
          <h3>About {{speaker.name}}</h3>
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-item>
      <button (click)="goToSpeakerTwitter(speaker)" clear item-left>
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        Tweet
      </button>
      <button (click)="openSpeakerShare(speaker)" clear item-right>
        <ion-icon name="share"></ion-icon>
        Share
      </button>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I am looking for a simple way to get them to swipe rather than stack. There are various plugins that do Tinder like swiping cards but I was wondering if there is a setting that can be given to ion-card to make the cards do a simple swipe (I am not looking for the Tinder visual effect) like a carousel.

I am using ionic V2.